# ng-repeat calling itself from the inside itself - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, razor

So I startet using `AngularJs` and I was wondering if it's possible to make some kind of nested functionality where I can call some `HTML` again inside itself.

In `Razor` we had something called `helpers` which where kinda like `C#`'s `methods` and in there my solution would look something like this:

```
@helper myHelper(int number){
    <p>@number</p>

    if(FlipCoin("head"))
    {
        myHelper(number++);
    }
}
```

but is there an equivelant in `AngularJs` and if so how would it be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `ng-template` solves the problem.

a solution could look like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myHelper.html">
    <p>
        hit
    </p>
    <div ng-template="'myHelper.html'"></div>
</script>

<div ng-template="'myHelper.html'"></div>
```

This code will ofcourse create an endless loop. But add some more logic to it and it's fixed.

[source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)